# Heroku not available outside the US and Europe?

Tags: heroku

I am a beginner developer.
I have created a web application that I would like to deploy on Heroku. But I read an article on a website from January 2022 that says: "Heroku only covers the US and European regions. This space is not suitable for a company with an application with customers in Asian countries. This limitation causes potential users outside of Europe and the US to turn to alternatives."

1. Can anyone confirm this please?

In my case, I myself reside in Europe and a significant portion of my customers will be in Africa and Asia.

2. Does this mean that my customers residing outside the US and Europe would not be able to access my site? Or what do they mean by this?

Comment: Where did you read this? It sounds like somebody got confused... [Heroku app can be deployed in a small number of regions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/regions), but that's just where the hosting is physically located. There should not be restrictions on where the running apps can be accessed from (aside from regions that have restricted / monitored Internet access).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you host using Heroku's servers, then the server you use will be *physically* located in the US or Europe.

That doesn't mean that customers in Asia or Africa can't access it, but it does mean that the data will have to be transferred over trans-continental network connections.

When compared to using servers that are physically located near your customers, this is relatively slow.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at their [Regions documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/regions#viewing-available-regions), you are partially correct.

**The common/shared runtime is only available in the US and EU, as of July 2022.**

```
heroku regions --common
ID  Location       Runtime
──  ─────────────  ──────────────
eu  Europe         Common Runtime
us  United States  Common Runtime
```

Heroku does offer more regions, like in Sydney & Tokyo, but that requires using their [Private Space plans](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/private-spaces) which allows you to spin up your own private Heroku instance in a few different regions.

```
$ heroku regions --private
ID         Location                 Runtime
─────────  ───────────────────────  ──────────────
dublin     Dublin, Ireland          Private Spaces
frankfurt  Frankfurt, Germany       Private Spaces
oregon     Oregon, United States    Private Spaces
sydney     Sydney, Australia        Private Spaces
tokyo      Tokyo, Japan             Private Spaces
virginia   Virginia, United States  Private Spaces
```

For the sake of answering the question; if your project can justify the Private Spaces cost, it is possible to use Heroku in more regions, like Asia and Eastern Europe. These regions are not available in the Common Runtime as of July 2022 though.

Comment: from $300 a month